# AzureDataFactory Incremental Load using Python

Tags: python, azure-data-factory, incremental-load

How do I create azure datafactory for incremental load using python?
Where should I mention file load option(Incremental Load:LastModifiedOn) while creating activity or pipeline??

We can do that using UI by selecting File Load Option. But how to do the same pragmatically using python?

Does python api for datafactory support this or not?

Comment: Hi,any updates? Does my answer helps you/

Answer (score 0):

According to this [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/incrementally-copy-new-files-by-lastmodifieddate-with-azure-data-factory/), you could only get the Incremental Load feature from ADF SDK by setting `modifiedDatetimeStart` and `modifiedDatetimeEnd` properties.

You could set the above properties in the `additional_properties` of azure_blob_dataset class.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My investigations suggest that the Python SDK has not yet implemented this feature.  I used the SDK to connect to my existing instance and fetched two example datasets.  I did not find anything that looked like the 'last modified date'.  I tried `dataset.serialize()` , `dataset.__dict__` , `dataset.properties.__dict__` .  I also tried `.__slots__` .

Trying `serialize()` is significant because there *ought* to be parity between the JSON generated in the GUI and the JSON generated by the Python.  The lack of parity suggests the SDK version lags behind the GUI version.

UPDATE: The SDK's are being updated.